# Is there a way to shorten my CountryViewController.m without hard coding?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I would like to know if there's a way to shorten my CountryViewController.m because I will be adding another else if statement every time I add a new country.

I am using a UITableViews that pushes a new table view.

```
RootViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    
    ASIA   = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    EU     = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [ASIA    addObject: @"China"];
    [ASIA    addObject: @"Japan"];
    [ASIA    addObject: @"Korea"];
    [EU      addObject: @"France"];
    [EU      addObject: @"Italy"];
    [EU      addObject: @"Switzerland"];

    self.title = @"Continent";
}

CountryViewController.m

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];

    if ([self.title isEqualToString: @"China"]) {
        _listOfCities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [_listOfCities addObject: @"Beijing"];
        [_listOfCities addObject: @"Hong Kong"];
    }

    else if ([self.title isEqualToString: @"Japan"]){
        _listOfCities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [_listOfCities addObject: @"Tokyo"];
    }

    else if ([self.title isEqualToString: @"Korea"]){
        _listOfCities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [_listOfCities addObject: @"Seoul"];
    }

    else if ([self.title isEqualToString: @"France"]){
        _listOfCities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [_listOfCities addObject: @"Paris"];
        [_listOfCities addObject: @"Versailles"];
    }

    else if ([self.title isEqualToString: @"Italy"]){
        _listOfCities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [_listOfCities addObject: @"Rome"];
    }

    else if ([self.title isEqualToString: @"Switzerland"]){
        _listOfCities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [_listOfCities addObject: @"Bern"];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I would say either a property list or a database... The entire logic is bad programming example here

Comment: But is there a way for this to be shorten without using plist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way is to use a [property list](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/index.html) and include that as a bundle resource (i.e. just add it to your project).

For example, if your property list looks like this:
[image]

You can then load it with

```
countries = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CountryData" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

and use it as a normal dictionary or array, i.e.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];

    NSString* countryName = self.title;
    NSDictionary* country = [countries objectForKey:countryName];
    NSArray* cities = [country objectForKey:@"Cities"];
    NSString* continent = [country objectForKey:@"Continent"];
    _listOfCities = cities;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Plist files can be edited easily in XCode.

Comment: When using a plist, how will I know that Beijing and Hong Kong is for China, and not for Korea?

Comment: For example, by adding the cities to the plist file under their respective parent country.

Comment: By that, I won't be using those else if statements?

Comment: Should I just use one plist for all the _listOfCities?

Comment: Where did you get the countries inside of `NSArray* cities = [countries objectForKey:countryName];` ?

Comment: OK, see my edited answer again :) This is just one example of how to model it.